# How can I select the exact number of items after applying the filter?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to select a group of items after applying the filter and it works until a certain number of items.

I use 'Areas' to select the set of items because sometimes it needs to select the first one, two, three... until ten items. The variable which determines how long the selection will be is called rangeA, rangeB and rangeC for SELECTION A, SELECTION B and SELECTION C, respectively. Also, the number of columns for each selection is always the same. After the selection is done it's copied and pasted for each selection. It works this way:

1. the filter is applied
2. the selection (A, B and C one per time) is copied
3. the selection is pasted on the "Worksheet 2"
   for selection A, B and C.

One observation is that I will always have items to select because "DATA" is too big, it has over 13 thousand items.

```
Sub SELECT()

    Dim area As Range
    Dim CellCount As Integer
    Dim firstCell As Range 'firstCell and lastCell determines how big the selection will be. 
    Dim lastCell As Range
    Dim rangeA, rangeB, rangeC As Variant
    rangeA = Range("v20").Value 'this is the cell where the number of rows I want (one to ten)
    rangeB = Range("v21").Value
    rangeC = Range("v22").Value
    
'############# SELECTION A #################'
'##########################################

Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Cells(11, 3)
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$11:$P$65").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
"FILTER X"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$11:$P$74").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="A"

    With ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Row, 1)
    
        'first cell will be the the first cell of Areas(1)
        Set firstCell = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells(1, 7)

        'Get last cell by looping through areas until their total cell count reaches 4.
        For Each area In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
            'first area may already contain more than N cells, in which case we just get its Nth cell and exit. "N" is rangeA, rangeB or rangeC
            'If this is not the case, we add up rows.Count of each area until we get more than N, and when that happens,
            'we get the cell of last area which is needed to get to N.
            If CellCount + area.Rows.Count >= Range("v20").Value Then
                Set lastCell = area.Cells(Range("v20").Value - CellCount, 0)
                Exit For
            End If
            CellCount = CellCount + area.Rows.Count
        Next
    End With
    'finally, from the firstCell and lastCell we can get the range of first N visible cells.

    ActiveSheet.Range(firstCell, lastCell).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet 2").Cells(8, 2)
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

''############# SELECTION B #################'
'##############################################

    Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Cells(11, 3)
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$11:$P$65").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
"FILTER X"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$11:$P$74").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="B"

    With ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Row, 1)
    

        Set firstCell = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells(1, 7)


        For Each area In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
        
                 If CellCount + area.Rows.Count >= Range("V21").Value Then
                    Set lastCell = area.Cells(Range("V21").Value - CellCount, 0)
                    Exit For
                End If
                CellCount = CellCount + area.Rows.Count
            Next
        'End If
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Range(firstCell, lastCell).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet 2").Cells(Range("v20").Value + 8, 2)
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
         Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS").Activate
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        
'############# SELECTION C  #######################'
'################################################

Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Cells(11, 3)
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$11:$P$65").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
"FILTER X"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$11:$P$74").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="C"

    With ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Row, 1)
    
        Set firstCell = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells(1, 7)


        For Each area In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas

            If CellCount + area.Rows.Count >= Range("V22").Value Then
                Set lastCell = area.Cells(Range("V22").Value - CellCount, 0)
                Exit For
            End If
            CellCount = CellCount + area.Rows.Count
        Next
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Range(firstCell, lastCell).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet 2").Cells(Range("v21").Value + Range("v20").Value + 8, 2)
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Worksheets("BASE DE DADOS").Activate
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

    
End Sub
```

Another observation is that when I run one selection alone it works perfectly fine (it can be one, two, three,... ten items). But when I run two selections (any combinations) it works until certain number of items, for rangeA and rangeB it works for 1 and 3 but it doesn't work for 3 and 3. In this last case it selects 3 items of A (correct) but only 1 item of B.

Also, it works for the three selections when the rangeA, rangeB and rangeC are respectively 3, 1, 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: At first look this is odd `.Resize(Rows.Count - ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Row` . `Range("B11").Row` is always 11 and `Rows.count` is probably 1,048,576
 so `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` will include all the blank lines below the data. Normally you would apply `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to the sheets  `UsedRange` only.

Comment: I highly suggest removing all use of `ActiveSheet` and `Selection`. Your code will run faster, the screen wont flicker and jitter around while the script executes. and it avoids a lot of errors to work with specific objects & Ranges instead of the ever-changing  `Selection`.

Comment: You can directly give a destination to `Range.Copy` so that it pastes the cells in a single line, no need to move `Selection` and then `PasteSpecial`. Also, if you're only moving values, you can just directly assign the values `DestinationRange.Value = SourceRange.Value` (this works even for multi-cell ranges, but not multiple seperate  areas)

Answer (score 2):

Make the selection a function so you can re-use same code for each selection.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub selectABC()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, rngTarget As Range
    Dim countA As Long, countB As Long, countC As Long, n As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsData = .Sheets("DATA")
        Set ws2 = .Sheets("worksheet 2")
    End With
    
    With wsData
        'these are the cells where the number of rows I want
        countA = 1 '.Range("v20").Value
        countB = 4 ' .Range("v21").Value
        countC = 4 ' .Range("v22").Value
    End With

   'selection A
   Set rngTarget = ws2.Range("B8")
   n = myselect(wsData, rngTarget, "FILTER X", "A", countA)
   
   'selection B
   Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(n)
   n = myselect(wsData, rngTarget, "FILTER X", "B", countB)
   
   'selection C
   Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(n)
   Call myselect(wsData, rngTarget, "FILTER X", "C", countC)
   
End Sub

Function myselect(wsData, rngTarget, f1, f2, maxrows) As Long

    Dim rng As Range, a As Range, rngVisible As Range, rngCopy As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, n As Long, m As Long
    
    With wsData
        
        lastrow = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    
        With .Range("A11:P" & lastrow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=f1 ' col J
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=f2 ' col G
            
            Set rngVisible = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If rngVisible Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox " Error no data", vbCritical
                Exit Function
            End If
            .AutoFilter
        End With
        'Debug.Print rngVisible.Address, f1, f2, lastrow
     
        n = 0
        m = 0
        For Each a In rngVisible.Areas
            For Each rng In a.Rows
                ' skip first headers
                If n > 0 Then
                    If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngCopy = rng
                    Else
                        Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, rng)
                    End If
                    m = m + 1 ' row count
                End If
                n = n + 1
                If n > maxrows Then Exit For
            Next
            If n > maxrows Then Exit For
        Next
        
        If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
             ' no data
        Else
            'Debug.Print rngCopy.Address
            rngCopy.Copy
            rngTarget.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                   SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ' remove selection shading
            rngTarget.Parent.Activate
            rngTarget.Select
        End If
    End With
    myselect = m
    MsgBox m & " rows copied for J=" & f1 & " G=" & f2

End Function
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks!!! Just one thing.. I need to select until column, how do I do that? I know this code below is necessary in order to select my FILTER X^

With .Range("A11:J" & lastrow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=f1 ' col J - FILTER X
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=f2 ' col G

But when it comes to copy the selection I want only from A11 to H. Any ideias and I close the question? ^^

Comment: @lucas Resize the rngCopy, change 2 lines `Set rngCopy = rng.Resize(, 8) ' A-H` and `Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, rng.Resize(, 8))`